# Override python lambdas default logging format

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to override the default logging format in python lambda. Followed this [blog post](https://medium.com/@aaanim/python-logging-in-aws-lambda-f9a71014d497)
and seems very straight forward in a nutshell doing this inside my lambda function:

```py
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
HANDLER = LOGGER.handlers[0]
HANDLER.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(“[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s”, “%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”))
```

But when executing it, my `LOGGER.handlers` has not handlers in it. So the override fails.
I have tried adding a new `StreamHandler` with its own formatter:

```py
LOGGER = Logger.factory(name)
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setFormatter(JSONFormatter())
LOGGER.add_handler(sh)
```

that works , BUT I get two of the same log lines for every line I try to log. One from my custom `StreamHandler` and its formatter, and one default lambda formatted line.
So seems like at the end I have two handlers.

My question is, where should I override the logging handler's format - when does lambda add its own handler ?

Answer (score 0):

I would at the start of the run, change the default python formatter.

```
import logging
logging.Formatter.format = my_format_function
```

I used the same method to override the `makeRecord` function to include more metadata.

```
import logging

def myMakeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None, another=None):
    """
    The normal python handler does not provide all the fields, so this enriches the message and formats it for logz.io.
    """
    if extra is None:
        extra = {}

    extra.update({'message': msg,
                  'logger': name,
                  'line_number': lno,
                  'path_name': fn})

    if func is not None:
        extra.update({'func_name': func})

    msg = json.dumps(extra)
    extra = None

    return original_makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=func, extra=extra)

logging.Logger.makeRecord = myMakeRecord
```